# Create Windowless Apps In Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, desktop, environment, windowless

How can I **create a windowless app** like dock or notification for Linux Distribution?
(My System runs Solus OS  - Linux Distro)

I want to **create desktop environment** and want such apps( with no title bar, no close, no minimize , no maximize buttons, and doesn't show in opened application list) Like a Dock app, Notification sidebar, etc,etc,....

How can I do this?

Please Help me.

*(Please do not add bad comments and stupid answers! I mean it!)*

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/.

Answer (score 0):

IT seems that Solus uses the MATE desktop environment, which is based on GNOME 2.  GTK2 has a [`gtk_window_set_decorated`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-decorated) function which should allow you to do what you want:

> By default, windows are decorated with a title bar, resize controls, etc. Some window managers allow GTK+ to disable these decorations, creating a borderless window. If you set the decorated property to `FALSE` using this function, GTK+ will do its best to convince the window manager not to decorate the window.

If you do not use the GTK2 toolkit, but some other GUI programming framework, it likely has a similar function.

Comment: Actually I installed the GNOME 3 DE distro of SOLUS 3